# Add class='myClass' to jQuery mobile generated input box in listview?

Tags: javascript, listview, jquery-mobile, render

If you provide this code to jQuery Mobile with `data-role="listview"` and `data-filter="true"`.

```
<ul maxlength="25" class="autocomplete ui-listview ui-listview-inset ui-corner-all ui-shadow" 
    data-role="listview" data-inset="true" data-filter="true" data-filter-placeholder="" 
    data-filter-theme="d">
</ul>
```

It renders the following code:

```
<ul maxlength= '25' class='autocomplete' data-role='listview' data-inset='true' 
   data-filter='true' data-filter-placeholder='' data-filter-theme='d'>

<form role="search" class="ui-listview-filter ui-bar-d ui-listview-filter-inset">
    <div class="ui-input-search ui-shadow-inset ui-btn-corner-all ui-btn-shadow ui-icon-searchfield ui-body-d">
        <input class="ui-input-text ui-body-d" data-type="search" placeholder="">

        <a data-mini="false" data-theme="d" data-iconpos="notext" data-icon="delete" data-wrapperels="span" 
            data-iconshadow="true" data-shadow="true" data-corners="true" href="#" class="ui-input-clear 
            ui-btn ui-btn-up-d ui-shadow ui-btn-corner-all ui-fullsize ui-btn-icon-notext ui-input-clear-hidden" title="clear text">
            <span class="ui-btn-inner">
                <span class="ui-btn-text">clear text</span>
                    <span class="ui-icon ui-icon-delete ui-icon-shadow">&nbsp;</span>
            </span>
        </a>
    </div>
</form>
```

**Question:**

If I want to add `class='myClass'` to this dynamically created input box, is there a vocabulary to do so, or can I inject it after being created?  Assume that I might have many such listview widgets on the page, so saying just use `class ui-input-text` is not good enough.

thanks!

Comment: Do it like this http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/d5ur3/