# jQuery mobile listview - can't add id to dynamic input box

Tags: listview, jquery-mobile

#### Setup

I'm using jQuery Mobile 1.4.2 to create an bunch of autocomplete dropdown control. ([Docs here.](http://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.4.2/listview-autocomplete/))

```
<ul data-role="listview" data-inset="true" data-filter="true" data-filter-reveal="true" data-filter-theme="b" id="listview-XXXXXX">
    <li class="ui-screen-hidden"><a href="#">Text</a></li>
    ...
</ul>
```

When rendering my page, jQuery Mobile turns this into the following HTML:

```
<form class="ui-filterable">
    <div class="ui-input-search ui-shadow-inset ui-input-has-clear ui-body-b ui-corner-all">
        <input data-type="search" placeholder="Filter items...">
        <a href="#" class="ui-input-clear ui-btn ui-icon-delete ui-btn-icon-notext ui-corner-all ui-input-clear-hidden" title="Clear text">Clear text</a>
    </div>
</form>
<ul data-role="listview" data-inset="true" data-filter="true" data-filter-reveal="true" data-filter-theme="b" id="listview-XXXXXX" class="ui-listview ui-listview-inset ui-corner-all ui-shadow">
    <li class="ui-screen-hidden"><a href="#" class="ui-btn ui-btn-icon-right ui-icon-carat-r">Text</a></li>
</ul>
```

So far so good.

#### What I want to do

I'd like to add an id to the dynamically-created `<input>` tag (so that I can see when the user updates it and fire a Javascript event elsewhere). This doesn't seem to come with the widget out-of-box, so I tried to add it myself like this:

```
$(document).on("listviewcreate", "", function (e, ui) {
    var newId = "question-" + e.target.id.substr(9);
    $(e.target).prev("form").find("input")attr("id", newId);
});
```

But no such id is added to the input field. (If I run that code in the Chrome console after the page loads (substituting `$(this)` with the listview's own id) it works fine. So I don't think there's anything wrong with that function I wrote.)

**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2Zx5g/)**

I found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20663490/436282) and tried out using the `listviewcreate` function. It doesn't seem to make a difference.

Is there something else I could be missing? Why might it work from the console but not when the page loads?

---

Edit: So my fiddle mysteriously works now. I guess there's something else wrong in our site somewhere that can't be reproduced with that minimal example.

---

Another edit: `$(e.target).prev("form")` seems to have nothing in it.

Comment: it's working, update jQM 1.4 libraries http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/2Zx5g/2/

Comment: I am using the latest library. It clearly *isn't* working for me.

Comment: check console http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/bT66J/1/

Comment: I understand how to use the dev tools and console to check the source. The ids are not added.

Comment: I'm not _questioning_ your skills. The IDs are added to `input` and are printed in console log `console.log()`.

Comment: As I've said before, in my case, no, they aren't.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/55095/discussion-between-omar-and-andrew-arnold).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The delay is creating filter input is caused by the new widget [*filterable*](http://api.jquerymobile.com/filterable/). Instead fo listening to `listviewcreate` event, listen to [`filterablecreate`](http://api.jquerymobile.com/filterable/#event-create) one. And use `.prop()` instead of `.attr()`.

```
$(document).on("filterablecreate", function (event, ui) {
  var newId = "question-" + $(event.target)[0].id.substr(9),
  $(event.target).prev("form").find("input").prop("id", newId);
});
```

> **[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/8wNeW/)**